# DOMDocument, adding surrounding <div> if needed

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I'm loading a DOMDocument as follows:

```
$dom->loadHtml($str_html_fragment, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

The extra arguments ensures that `saveHTML` just outputs the fragment, and doesn't add surrounding doctypes or html tags.

`$str_html_fragment` could be either something like

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<span>one</span>
<span>two</span>
```

If there is already a single root element in the fragment (like the `<ul`>), I want to add a class to it, but if the fragment consists of a number of sibling nodes, I want to surround the fragment with a new `<div>` and add the new class to that instead, to give either:

```
<ul class="new-class">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<div class="new-class">
    <span>one</span>
    <span>two</span>
</div>
```

From looking at the docs I can't see how to count whether there are multiple elements are at the 'top level' or not, or how to add a surrounding root element after `loadHTML` has been called.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you do `echo $dom->saveHTML();` with the second example (two span elements - you actually get out `<span>one<span>two</span></span>` which isn't going to work anyway - I assume.

Comment: Why don't you just surround with your `<div>` every time? Then you don't even need to manipulate the DOM. You would just have `$html = sprintf('<div class="%s">%s</div>', 'new-class', $html);`

Comment: @NigelRen thanks didn't know that - was trying to write defensively and had hadn't actually run into my own test scenario with 2 spans :( my bad

Comment: @ChristopheDeliens the problem would be that the extra <div> could potentially mess up layout or alter the effect of CSS rules (which is still a danger for the 2-span case, but adding the surrounding class is more important)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a description of the problem and a solution at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.savehtml.php):

> When saving HTML fragment initiated with LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED option,
>   it will end up being "broken" as libxml requires root element. libxml
>   will attempt to fix the fragment by adding closing tag at the end of
>   string based on the first opened tag it encounters in the fragment.
>
> For an example:
>
> `<h1>Foo</h1><p>bar</p>`
>
> will end up as:
>
> `<h1>Foo<p>bar</p></h1>`
>
> Easiest workaround is adding root tag yourself and stripping it later:
>
> $html->loadHTML('' . $content .'', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED
>   | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
>
> $content = str_replace(array('','') , '' ,
>   $html->saveHTML());

When I apply this to your case, I end up with the following code, which can serve as proof of concept:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$str_html_fragment = <<<'EOD'
<span>one</span>
<span>two</span>
EOD;

$dom->loadHTML('<html>' . $str_html_fragment .'</html>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$i = 0;
foreach($dom->childNodes as $top) {
    foreach($top->childNodes as $node) {
        echo "Node type is " . $node->nodeType . "\n";
        if($node->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) $i += 1;
    }
}

echo "We have $i element nodes\n";

echo str_replace(array('<html>','</html>') , '' , $dom->saveHTML());
?>
```

This code genrates the following output:

```
Node type is 1
Node type is 3
Node type is 1
We have 2 element nodes
<span>one</span>
<span>two</span>
```